# How to install libyajl package in ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04

I am trying to install libvert package for which this error is coming:

```
**configure: error: You must install the libyajl library & headers to compile libvirt**
```

How to resolve this error, i tried below steps:

1. Downloaded package from `git/lloyd`
2. `./configure`

please help me to complete the installation. After `./configure` which step should i do?

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get install libyajl-dev
`?

Comment: I do not see an error in when you tried to compile lloyd-yajl. It requires cmake so you must install cmake first. Debian-based systems are notorious in crippling packages, aka splitting them up into a gazillion subpackages, without giving the user a simple way to un-cripple the whole system - in the days of terabyte hdds ...

Answer (score 8):

Please compile the yajl.

```
root@localhost:/tmp# git clone git://github.com/lloyd/yajl

root@localhost:/tmp# cd yajl

root@localhost:/tmp/yajl# ./configure && make && make install
```

If you are faced with following error message, please install cmake package.

And then compile the yajl.

```
root@localhost:/tmp/yajl# ./configure && make && make install
== removing old build files
== running CMake in build directory
./configure: 41: ./configure: cmake: not found
The "cmake" program is required to configure yajl.
It's available from most ports/packaging systems and http://cmake.org

root@localhost:/tmp/yajl# apt-get install cmake

root@localhost:/tmp/yajl# ./configure && make && make install
```

Thanks.